# So how can I see the logs in Jelly Bean?

Tags: android, logging, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I used to use an app called Log Collector to see system logs. It would send them to my email or via bluetooth,

However, on Jelly Bean the "read log" permission for apps no longer exists and apps can't read the logs, and Log Collector is obviously no exception.

So does one now need to root the device to see system logs? There must be a way for the user to read them. I don't need to access them from an application, I need to read them as a human being. Is there a way?

Comment: I just tested the Log Collector app on my Galaxy Nexus updated to Android version 4.1.1 JellyBean, and it worked fine... the first time, then subsequently did not.  So it seems that it can work with Jelly Bean.  I will play with it a bit more and report my findings to the developer of Log Collector.

Comment: What do you mean by "work fine"? It does "work", but it only gets the entries in the logs that it has access to, which is close to nothing. I don't thing it's an issue in Log Collector, it's that the permission for applications to read system logs no longer exists. The question is what other way we have available to read user logs, without rooting the device...

Comment: By 'Works Fine' I mean that it is collecting and uploading the log content that I have created from my own application. Also ignore the part of my first comment, where I state it only worked the first time. It works every time (for me).

Comment: Unless your requirement is to do this "on the go" without access to a development host, `adb logcat` would normally be your first resort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer in this google groups thread:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/android-developers/READ_LOGS/android-developers/6U4A5irWang/8xOi74KfRIYJ

the message by Mark Murphy replying to Matteo Sisti Sette (which is me).

(it doesn't seem to be possible to link to a particular message, is it?)

**POWER + VOLUME_UP + VOLUME_DOWN** will generate a report and a screenshot that you can send via email or upload to Drive (ridiculous you can't share it in an arbitrary way such as send via bluetooth or open as text file, but anyways).

(seems you have to hold them for a while and the action is launched when you *release* them)

At first I thought he was making fun of me and that would just reboot or something, but then I tried and it  works.

Comment: I haven't had any luck with this approach - am I missing something obvious? Depending on the order in which I press the buttons, either the volume control or the phone options dialog appears, but nothing relating to logs. If I keep the power button pressed for more than a couple of seconds, the device reboots.

Comment: This worked for me, it's awkward. Hold the middle of your volume rocker down, then hold the power button down. Keep them pressed, and then the phone vibrates. After a few seconds, gmail will foreground with a formatted log report.

Comment: It works for me too, though I always have to do it a dozen of times until I do it in the right order (I guess) which I never figured out. I'll try your order to see if it systematically works. It's a very shitty combination, anyway.

Comment: @user291701 how will you able to do.I have follow steps given bu you many times but not gets gmail opened.The only things happens to me is that device gets rebooted all the time like Michael said.If you know proper way of doing it let me know

Answer (score 5):

*Quote from Google+ and credits to +Ian Clifton :*

"If you go into the **developer options** of a device running **4.2**, you can check the box to **add the Bug Report option to the power menu**. This also adds it to the quick notifications menu (not sure of the proper name, but slide down the notification shade with two fingers on a phone or on the right side of a tablet).﻿"

*..and that would be right answer..*  *Cheers*